# Pywhatkit.playonyt(): This site can’t be reached. (python 3.6.0)

Tags: python-3.6

I am trying to make a personal assistent but when I try to use `pywhatkit.playonyt()` it opens a non available page. This is my code:

```
if 'play' in command:
    song = command.replace('play', '')
    talk('playing ' + song)
    pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a known bug in PyWhatKit, we fixed it in the newer version, use the following code

```
if 'play' in command:
song = command.replace('play ', '')
talk('playing ' + song)
pywhatkit.playonyt(song, use_api=True)
```

This problem usually happens if you are using a vpn, tor, or some other reasons that are country specific.